# What falls under "Data Oriented Design"?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, latency

Data Oriented Design is most formally introduced by this [Sony Research document](http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/gcapaustralia09/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf) and [this document](http://dice.se/wp-content/uploads/Introduction_to_Data-Oriented_Design.pdf).

Beyond the obvious, however, I was wondering what other aspects of programming fall under "Data Oriented Design"? Would SIMD/SSE instructions? How about anything which reduces TLB misses? Or CPU-affinity?

So far my only understanding of DOD is "anything which reducing cache misses". Is there anything not obvious which falls under Data Oriented Design?

Comment: Can you state what you believe is "obvious" in DOD?  That would make it much easier for experts to list the answers that you consider "beyond the obvious".

Comment: Basically the example given in the PDFs- where instead of an Arrayist containing objects, each object having five attributes, you have 5 arraylists, one containing just the attribute. That seems to be all the documents describe and that this improves the cache hits. Hence my question is, "is DOD anything that reduces cache misses?"

Comment: For what it's worth - I've read about DOD for years.  It was **always** described as "cache sensitive" programming, but it **always** provided only that same one "collection striping" example.  Since any container of `X` can be retrofitted to use this technique, "the data striping *optimization*" is probably a better term than any sort of *design* philosophy.

Comment: @DrewDormann So would you count SIMD/SSE instructions being DOD?- because they improve the performance throughput? I think one could argue they are a data design (designing parallel computation paths)?

Comment: You've read up on DOD and you're not positive what it is.  I would assume the same from other programmers and just avoid the term.  Terms already exist like "cache misses" and "SIMD" that people understand well.  And the more encompassing idea of "improving performance throughput" has a well-known term too.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious to me is that DOD is about data centric design.
To see it more in context. I take the obvious first impression of it counter part OOD.
Object oriented is modeling your solution to real world model. Wich is nice as that easier to comprehend. But your hardware doesn't like it that way.
Data oriented is data centered. Of how the platform likes it.

SMID, Cache line
Are some of the platform details. 
But there is much more to it then cache lines.

Data oriented makes concurrent programming much easier then OoD way.
OOD is much more friendly for humans. As every body knows the real world.
DOD you need to know much more about the platform, to model the data to get the most performance. And also what for transforms you do on that data.

DOD is about, know the platform and know problem domain.  To get the most out of it with DOD.

Comment: An example of both worlds would make the idea even better imho.